# How to hide AppBar in the application created in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this code below, I want to hide the bar app, is it possible? I've tried straight through the Android Theme but I did not get Success. :(

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextField(
          autofocus: false,
          controller: controller,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
          onSubmitted: (url) => launchUrl(),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: "Digite a URL",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
            onPressed: () => launchUrl(),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 5):

To hide the appBar simply set the appBar property as null in any screen. This change will be reflected in IOS as well as Android. :)

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
       url: "https://flutter.dev/",                    // Your url
       appBar: null                                    // No action bar will build
       );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just don't build the AppBar depending on a boolean flag:

```
return WebviewScaffold(
    appBar: _ifHideAppBar ? null : AppBar(
        ...
    ),
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Visibility` widget to do this but note that appBar required type of `PreferredSizedWidget` and `Visibility` is of type `Widget` because of that we have to wrap with `PreferedSize` widget and give sizes(Checking if `null` is less code but in this way you can have your custom app bar).

```
WebviewScaffold(
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 56),
    child: Visibility(
      visible: true,
      child: AppBar(),
    ),
  ),
  //....
);
```